# Unable to read matrix file with Read10X

Tags: r

I got an error while reading a Read10X file, see the following scripts 
`

```
mln28_1 <-Read10X(data.dir ="C:/Users/G19-013_SampleID_2_14mar19_Mln28_1/")
```

Show Traceback

> error in scan(file, nmax = nz, quiet = TRUE, what = list(i = integer(), : scan() expected 'an integer', got '2Âªø'
>       3.scan(file, nmax = nz, quiet = TRUE, what = list(i = integer(), j =integer(), x = numeric()))2.readMM(file = matrix.loc)1.Read10X(data.dir = "C:/Users/xkalaj/Documents/Bcell_fateProject/G19013_SampleID_2_14mar19_Mln28_1")
>   Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Smells like a character encoding issue. `scan() expected 'an integer', got '2Âªø`.

Comment: Could also be a corrupted file. I have never seen that type of encoding coming from `cellranger`  (assuming `Read10x` is the fucntion to read in `10x RNA-seq` data.

Comment: I just saw the `1.readMM` are you reading a matrix in ` Harwell-Boeing` format and then trying to use `Read10x`? If so, you may want to check `Read10X_h5` .

Comment: It was a corrupted file. But, the problem gets solved after file replacement. Thanks all for the suggestions.